# What is the best way to save the calendar data in Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, calendar, customization

I am building an angular component for handling custom calendars and events. Once an event is created I save the given data to the firestore database as single documents.

Document sample :

```
 {
  "name" : "test event",
  "description" :"sample test event for check",
  "startdate":"8/12/2021",
  "enddate":"8/12/2021",
  "color":"#11111",
  "userid":"user1"
 }
```

So on creating each event the similar data structure will be saved as individual documents. We can filter the custom calendar with a date range and also support showing multiple user events in a single calendar.

But using the above document structure, when we try to fetch a large amount of data it leads to higher costing to the server. How can I organize these data on an individual basis or else? Can Anyone suggest your opinion about this?

Answer (score 1):

This structure should be good for the use case as it won't hit any per document limit (storing events in an array may hit 1 MB per document size limit) and you can easily execute most of the queries.

> How can I organize these data on an individual basis or else?

You have the `userid` field in document and user's events can be filtered using `.where("userid", "==", curUserId)`. Other way would be to use sub-collections:

```
users -> {userId} -> events -> {eventId}
(col)     (doc)      (col)      (doc)
```

This way you won't have to store user's UID in every document as it is already grouped in sub-collections.

> when we try to fetch a large amount of data it leads to higher costing to the server

Firestore costs are totally based on your usage. If your application has a lots of users then the costs will be higher.